# I made a sub a function but get an error, what's wrong?

Tags: excel, vba, function, output

I wrote a sub in VBA for excel. i did that to debug and step through the code. I changed it to a function and only changed the Dims and the last line for the output, it get an error on the spread sheet, What am I doing wrong? I commented out the dims needed when it was a sub

```
Function CostPerTon(FeedType As String) As Double

'Dim FeedType As String, count#, CostPerTon#
Dim count#

'FeedType = "Duck - Comercial - Starter - 1 to 25 Days"

Sheets("Formulations").Activate

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

i = 1

Dim IngredientCost As Double
Dim MyArray(100) As Variant


Do While i < count + 1

    IngredientCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FeedType, Range("1:1048576"), i + 2, 0) _
     * Worksheets("Costs").Cells(i + 2, 2) * (1 / 1000)
    MyArray(i) = IngredientCost

    i = i + 1

Loop

CostPerTon = WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyArray)

End Function
```

Comment: Did you place this function in a STANDARD CODE MODULE or is it in a worksheet module?

Comment: Also, you cannot activate a sheet from a user defined function when called from a worksheet as a formula.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't know. I went to the developer tab, clicked on Visual Basic, and on the left window called Project - VBAproject i right clicked, insert, module... is that standard?

Comment: And you shouldn't reference ranges in a UDF that were not passed as a parameter to the function, i.e. 'A:A'

Comment: Yes, that is standard. Is it called, Module1?

Comment: how do I access that worksheet info then?

Comment: No, you have it in the correct place, a standard code module. That is apparently not  your problem. So, what error do you get?

Comment: module 5 but same idea. how do I make it a function then? how do I adapt the code?

Comment: `count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Formulations").Range("A:A"))`

Comment: #VALUE! is the error I get

Comment: `IngredientCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FeedType, Sheets("Formulations").Range("1:1048576"), i + 2, 0) _`

Comment: Looks like Scott is leading you in the right direction... but you should rework your range references so that all are passed as arguments to your function.

Comment: And if you're just summing the values you don't need an array.